# Pass options in verbatim environment inside another environment

Tags: environments, verbatim, optional-arguments

I want to define a new environment (here `testenv`), which is going to include text in verbatim mode. So, I have the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{testenv}
{
\selectlanguage{english}
\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
\Verbatim
}
{
\endVerbatim
\normalsize
\selectlanguage{greek}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{testenv}
This is a test. 
\end{testenv}

\end{document}
```

However, I need some optional arguments in the verbatim environment. How should I pass these options e.g. `commandchars`, `commentchar` ?

**P.S.** I make use of the `fancyvrb` package.

Comment: There are some `verbatim` related packages that could do what you want ...

Comment: @juanuni I already use `fancyvrb` package. Isn't this enough?

Comment: There are anothers packages, `verbatim` package an others, sorry I don't remember the others ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine the way `Verbatim` works using `\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment`, adding the `formatcom` key to execute `format`ting `com`mands at the start of the `Verbatim` environment. Since the environment scope limits the extent of what happens with the content of `formatcom`, there is no need to reset it at the end:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{Verbatim}
  {commandchars = \\\{\},
   commentchar = !,
   formatcom = {\selectlanguage{english}
                \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont}}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}

\begin{Verbatim}
This is \textcolor{red}{red}. 
!This is a comment.
\end{Verbatim}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

This provides for a clean interface.